# Авторизация в Java используя HttpClient

Tags: авторизация, java

У меня стоит задача такая, взять данные у одного сайта(нашего корпоративного, не с интернета, но это думаю не важно), к базе не имею доступа и сказали не дадут, хотите парсите со страницы. В общем в этой теме впервые, раньше парсила только с xml или целую html страницу полностью))) А сейчас нужно сначала пройти авторизацию, потом ввести в поисковик id нужного человека и оттуда вытаскивать результат. Два дня вот копаюсь как можно реализовать. Нашла несколько возможных вариантов. С использованием httpclient, но мне выдает страницу ввода пароли, дальше не идет. То есть ввожу страницу после ввода пароли и имени пользователя, но опять же направляют на страницу с запросом пароля. Помогите пожалуйста.

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public class HttpBasicAuth {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        DefaultHttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        Client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user1", "123456789"));

        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://10.10.151.90/default.aspx");
        HttpResponse response = Client.execute(httpGet);

        System.out.println("response = " + response);

        BufferedReader breader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        StringBuilder responseString = new StringBuilder();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = breader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            responseString.append(line);
        }

        breader.close();
       String responseStr = responseString.toString();
        System.out.println("responseStr = " + responseStr);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Какой тип авторизации на сайте? Если не BASIС, то вероятнее всего нужно все-таки использовать метод POST и еще более вероятно, что при этом используется протокол HTTPS. Неплохо бы задать эти вопросы тем, кто вам поставил такую задачу.

Comment: + не забывайте про Encode/Decode данных, при послании и получения запроса. А так согласен с комментарием выше - запросы на авторизацию в большинстве случаев это POST запросы

Comment: сделала как Вы и посоветовали, но вопрос не решила:(
http://hashcode.ru/questions/334367/%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5-java-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3

Answer (score 0):

Без знания внутреннего устройства автоматизируемого сайта, добиться желаемого результата с помощью HttpClient будет достаточно сложно - только методом проб и ошибок подбирать нужный тип авторазиции.

В Вашем случае удобнее использовать инструменты автоматизации браузера, такие как Selenium. Я бы рекомендовал Selenide: https://ru.selenide.org/

Ваш код мог бы выглядеть:

```
  open("/login");
  $("#login").setValue("user");
  $("#password").setValue("password"); 
  $("#submit").click();
  $(".message").shouldHave(text("Привет"));
```