# Авторизация на сайте

Tags: авторизация, java, синтаксический-анализ

Этот вопрос уже [задавался](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/330885/%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-java-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%8F-httpclient?)

> **Цитата** 
>   У меня стоит задача такая, взять данные у одного сайта(нашего корпоративного, не с интернета, но это думаю не важно), к базе не имею доступа и сказали не дадут, хотите парсите со страницы. В общем в этой теме впервые, раньше парсила только с xml или целую html страницу полностью))) А сейчас нужно сначала пройти авторизацию, потом ввести в поисковик id нужного человека и оттуда вытаскивать результат. Два дня вот копаюсь как можно реализовать. Нашла несколько возможных вариантов. С использованием httpclient, но мне выдает страницу ввода пароли, дальше не идет. То есть ввожу страницу после ввода пароли и имени пользователя, но опять же направляют на страницу с запросом пароля. Помогите пожалуйста.

Там мне посоветовали:

> **Цитата** 
>   Какой тип авторизации на сайте? Если не BASIС, то вероятнее всего нужно все-таки использовать метод POST и еще более вероятно, что при этом используется протокол HTTPS. Неплохо бы задать эти вопросы тем, кто вам поставил такую задачу.
>   (25 Июн 1:39)a_gura
>   не забывайте про Encode/Decode данных, при GET и POST запросах, а так же при получении данных . А так согласен с @a_gura - запросы на авторизацию в большинстве случаев это POST запросы

Начала читать книгу Jeff Heaton "HTTP Programming Recipes for Java Bots", разбиралась в примерах полной уверенностью что это то что мне нужно. 
Так вот по этому примеру я сделала:

`CookieUtility` и `FormUtility` я взяла из книги

CookieUtility.java

```
 import java.net.*;
    import java.util.*;
    public class CookieUtility {
        // Map that holds all of the cookie values.
        private Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        public Map<String, String> getMap() {
            return this.map;
        }

        /**
        * Load any cookies from the specified URLConnection
        * object. Cookies will be located by their Set-Cookie
        * headers. Any cookies that are found can be moved to a
        * new URLConnection class by calling saveCookies.
        * 
        * @param http
        * The URLConnection object to load the cookies from.
        */
        public void loadCookies(URLConnection http) {
            String str;
            int n = 1;
            do {
                str = http.getHeaderFieldKey(n);
                if ((str != null) && str.equalsIgnoreCase("Set-Cookie")) {
                    str = http.getHeaderField(n);
                    StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer(str, "=");
                    String name = tok.nextToken();
                    String value = tok.nextToken();
                    this.map.put(name, value);
                }
                n++;
            } while (str != null);
        }

        /**
        * Once you have loaded cookies with loadCookies, you can
        * call saveCookies to copy these cookies to a new HTTP
        * request. This allows you to easily support cookies.
        * 
        * @param http
        * The URLConnection object to add cookies to.
        */
        public void saveCookies(URLConnection http) {
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            Set<String> set = this.map.keySet();
            for (String key : set) {
                String value = this.map.get(key);
                if (str.length() > 0) {
                    str.append("; ");
                }
                str.append(key + "=" + value);
            }
            http.setRequestProperty("Cookie", str.toString());
        }
    }
```

FormUtility.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
public class FormUtility {
    // The charset to use for URL encoding. should always be UTF-8.
    private final static String encode = "UTF-8";
    private static Random random = new Random();

    //Generate a boundary for a multipart form.
    public static String getBoundary() {
        return "---------------------------" + randomString() + 
                 randomString()
                 + randomString();
    }

    /**
     * Parse a URL query string. Return a map of all of the
     * name value pairs.
     * 
     * @param form
     * The query string to parse.
     * @return A map of name-value pairs.
     */
     public static Map<String, String> parse(String form) {
         Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<String, String>();
         StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer(form, "&");
         while (tok.hasMoreTokens()) {
             String str = tok.nextToken();
             StringTokenizer tok2 = new StringTokenizer(str, "=");
             if (!tok2.hasMoreTokens()) {
                 continue;
             }
             String left = tok2.nextToken();
             if (!tok2.hasMoreTokens()) {
                 left = encode(left);
                 result.put(left, null);
                 continue;
             }

             String right = tok2.nextToken();
             right = encode(right);
             result.put(left, right);
        }
         return result;
     }

     private static String encode(String str) {
         try {
             return URLEncoder.encode(str, encode);
         } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
             return str;
         }
     }

     protected static String randomString() {
         return Long.toString(random.nextLong(), 36);
     }


    /*
     * The boundary used for a multipart post. This field is
     * null if this is not a multipart form and has a value if
     * this is a multipart form.
     */
     private String boundary;
     private OutputStream os;
     private boolean first;

    /**
     * Prepare to access either a regular, or multipart, form.
     * 
     * @param os
     * The stream to output to.
     * @param boundary
     * The boundary to be used, or null if this is
     * not a multipart form.
     */
     public FormUtility(OutputStream os, String boundary) {
         this.os = os;
         this.boundary = boundary;
     }

     //Add a file to a multipart form.
     public void add(String name, File file) throws IOException {
         if (this.boundary != null) {
             boundary();
             writeName(name);
             write("; filename=\"");
             write(file.getName());
             write("\"");
             newline();
             write("Content-Type: ");
             String type = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(file.getName());
             if (type == null) {
                 type = "application/octet-stream";
             }
             writeln(type);
             newline();
             byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
             int nread;
             InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
             while ((nread = in.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) >= 0) {
                 this.os.write(buf, 0, nread);
             }
             newline();
         }
     }

     // Add a regular text field to either a regular or multipart form.
     public void add(String name, String value) throws IOException {
         if (this.boundary != null) {
             boundary();
             writeName(name);
             newline();
             newline();
             writeln(value);
         } else {
             if (!this.first) {
                 write("&");
             }
             write(encode(name));
             write("=");
             write(encode(value));
         }
         this.first = false;
     }
     //Complete the building of the form.
     public void complete() throws IOException {
         if (this.boundary != null) {
             boundary();
             writeln("--");
             this.os.flush();
         }
     }

     // Generate a multipart form boundary.
     private void boundary() throws IOException {
         write("--");
         write(this.boundary);
     }

     // Create a new line by displaying a carriage return and linefeed.
     private void newline() throws IOException {
         write("\r\n");
     }

     // Write the specified string, without a carriage return and line feed.
     private void write(String str) throws IOException {
         this.os.write(str.getBytes());
     }

     // Write the name element for a multipart post.
     private void writeName(String name) throws IOException {
         newline();
         write("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"");
         write(name);
         write("\"");
     }

     //Write a string, with a carriage return and linefeed.270 HTTP Programming Recipes for Java Bots
     protected void writeln(String str) throws IOException {
         write(str);
         newline();
     }
}
```

И собственно мой парсер

Parser.java

```
package parser;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class Parser {
    private CookieUtility cookies = new CookieUtility();

      private boolean login(String username, String password) throws IOException {
          URL url = new URL("http://10.10.10.90/Account/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fdefault.aspx");
          HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
          http.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
          http.setDoOutput(true);
          OutputStream os = http.getOutputStream();
          FormUtility form = new FormUtility(os, null);
          form.add("login_name", URLEncoder.encode(username));
          form.add("login_password", URLEncoder.encode(password));
          form.complete();
          http.getInputStream();
          cookies.loadCookies(http);

          return (cookies.getMap().containsKey("ASP.NET_SessionId"));
      }

      public String downloadPage(URL url, int timeout) throws IOException {
          StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
          byte buffer[] = new byte[8192];
          URLConnection http = url.openConnection();
          http.setConnectTimeout(10000);
          InputStream s = http.getInputStream();
          int size = 0;
          do {
              size = s.read(buffer);
              if (size != -1)
                  result.append(new String(buffer, 0, size));
          } while (size != -1);

          return result.toString();
      }

      public void process(String username, String password) throws IOException {
          if(login(username,password)) {
              URL url = new URL("http://10.10.10.90/default.aspx");
              String buffer = downloadPage(url,10000);
              System.out.println(buffer);
          } else {
              System.out.println("Authorization error..");
          }
      }

      public static void main(String args[]) {
          try {
              Parser p = new Parser();
              p.process("d.aim", "432545");
          } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }        
  }
```

Вроде все есть, ловим куки, передаем POST запрос, но все равно получаю страницу с запросом авторизации. Может дело в том что авторизация на этом сайте реализована на джаваскрипте? Но вроде если читать ту вышеупомянутую книгу это не должно быть проблемой. 
Так в чем я ошиблась? Что сделала не так? Или может я вообще неправильно делаю? Помогите решить, уже не первую неделю бьюсь с этой авторизацией:(

Comment: Гм, а что мешает посмотреть исходящие запросы при аутентификации и просто их воспроизвести в приложении? FireBug/WebInspector/Charley/etc вам в помощь.

Comment: Вы про снифферы? Так я отследила и поняла где у меня ошибка, там вообще оказывается один гет один пост запрос, вроде все так и сделала, только не знаю как быть со строками вроде
X-Coolite: delta=true\r\n
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8\r\n
Accept: */*\r\n
Referer:
их тоже включать в хедэры?
Они должны быть абсолютно идентичны строчка за строчкой?

Comment: Через сниффер гляньте-ка во кладку Cookies после авторизации, иногда после ввода логина и пароля для получения данных с другой страницы вам надо сохранять cookie, а при следующих запросах не только в header прописывать список cookie. В случае с httpclient'ом к экземпляру класса надо прикручивать BasicCookieStore (если создаете хранилище cookie вручную) или CookieStore, если получать при помощи метода getCookieStore(). Насчет заголовков, сам прописываю не все, только Cookie, Host, Accept-Encoding, ну и Referer.
p.s. отвечу быстрее вк (в профиле адрес), потом тут ответ запостите.